# VS2012 Debugger Error - "Connection request was rejected .. Ensure ... debugger is running in 'No Authentication' Mode."

Tags: windows, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I'm having an issue with Visual Studio Remote Debugging:

**Machine 2:** 
Windows 2007 > no domain > no firewall > **Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor 64-bit 9.0.2122 (c) 2008** > Options... > No Authentication, Port=4015, allow any user to debug=true > OK > It says listening on 4015 in No Authentication Mode

**Machine 1:** 
Windows 2007 > no domain > no firewall > **Visual Studio 2012** > DEBUG > Attach to Process > Transport = Remote(no authentication) > Attach to Machine2:4015 > Attach > It says:

**Unable to connect to 'Machine2:4015'. Connection request was rejected by the remote debugger. Ensure that the remote debugger is running in 'No Authentication' Mode.**

The remote debugger clearly says it's running in "No Authentication Mode".

What's the problem with VS2012 / MSVSMON?

What more does it want from me?!? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this same issue, but with VS2013. I couldn't connect with or without authentication. In my case it's C++ code but complicated by having two domains.

Turns out the remote tools are specific to the version and update level of Visual Studio:

> You must install the update version of the Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2013 that matches the update version of your Visual Studio installation.

Once I updated to the correct msvsmon.exe I could connect to the remote PC.

Answer (score 4):

in my case the message was

> Ensure that the remote debugger is running in `'windows Authentication'`
>   Mode.

its easy to add your Authentication, just fallow these steps..

1. in remote debugger go to `tools` -> `Options`
2. in the authentication mode chose `windows authentication` then click
   on `permeation button`
3. click add
4. `write everyone` then click `Ckeck Names` then `ok`

[image]
thats it hope it help you,, and happy debugging!

Answer (score 3):

According to this [post](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2012/03/22/troubleshoot-remote-debugging-of-managed-code/) it is not possible to remote debug C# in non-authenticated mode:

> First: you need to be aware that Remote Debugging Managed Code is only
>   available when you use the authenticated mode, if you run the remote
>   debugger without authentication you can debug only Native Code

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I discover that I had installed `visual studio 2013` and `visual tools remote debugger 2019`. I installed the `version 2013 of remote debugger` and my problem was resolved.